# The order of arrangement of windows

Tags: c++, qt, window, qwidget

Sorry for my English. I need to implement the order of the `QWidget`. I have a stack of objects `QWidget`. And I need to place the window in the order they appear in a stack.

For example:

Stack: `window1` -> `window2` -> `window3`

From this example `window2` always closes `window3`, but it, in turn, closes `window1`.

Is there any such functionality in Qt? I am not limited to the `QWidget`. Maybe somehow you can specify the order \ windows priority?

The `QStackedWidget` class provides a stack of widgets where only **one** widget is visible at a time. I need to get all the widgets to be seen and they cover each other in order of priority.

Maybe there are some flags. `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint` it does not suit me, so the widget \ windows a lot and one should cover everything. And all in order of priority.

Comment: If one window was not closing the other I would think of modal dialogs.

Comment: @AlexanderVX I need to get all the windows were opened simultaneously. should be active only on the first priority of the window. whether there is a possibility to deactivate qt window?

Comment: Maybe you can provide a picture and rewrite the question. "All the windows opened simultaneously" and/or the rest you have written in the question make it not clear. Otherwise it seems to be a stack of modal dialogs where one belong to another 1->2->3. But I cannot answer without understanding the question better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can close the child window explicitly in the close event of a window, something like:

```
class WindowWithChildWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    WindowWithChildWindow(QWidget *child)
        : m_child(child)
    { }
    ....
protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *e) override
    {
        if (!m_child || m_child->close())
            e->accept(); // close this window
        else // child ignored the close request in its close event
            e->ignore(); // do not close this window
    }
    ....
};
```